# Set HttpClient Timeout for Azure function app

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I have a dotnet Function App running on Azure which uses a [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0) to call another API, but it times out after a bit (100 seconds I believe, which should be the default). I've tried updating the [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-7.0) field to 30 minutes or 60 minutes (e.g. `httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);`) but this doesn't change anything.

For dotnet APIs, this timeout value [is set by the server, not the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48410703/12303271), which works fine for my API (I can call the same code in a dotnet API context and it works fine), but I need to add this to my function app context. Correct me if I'm wrong, but function apps don't have a Web.config file but only use app settings/connection strings and I couldn't find an app setting for this. Any way to get around this?

*Note: This is not due to the actual function apps timing out, I can still run code in the function app after the http client times out. The issue is configuring execution timeout specifically for Http client, just within a function app context*

Comment: Have you tried to use Polly's timeout policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, implement this guide here: https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/ to increase the timeout and set the cancel per-request

In my case, I'm calling another API on Azure so it has a hard limit of 230 seconds, but this is still better than 100 seconds and can actually set a timeout if I want.

Answer (score -1):

In [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout) it is mentioned that max timeout for http trigger function is 230 seconds regardless of timeout:

> The timeout duration for functions in a function app is defined by the functionTimeout property in the host.json project file. <...>
> Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to respond to a request. This is because of the default idle timeout of Azure Load Balancer.

From this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/758823/httptrigger-response-timeout) it seems that 230 seconds limit cannot be extended.

Comment: The function app timeout isn't my issue though, it's specifically the HttpClient timeout while waiting for an API call to complete. After my HttpClient times out (100 seconds iirc), my function app still runs to handle the response and does other cases, probably about 2 minutes total (function app doesn't time out). I can double the HttpClient timeout time without causing the function app to timeout, which is what I want to do. I do not need to increase the function app timeout time since my api endpoint takes about 2-3 minutes to call and can be done within the 230 seconds